# Access Separate rows of excel sheet in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, windows

I want my main script to read a excel sheet into separate rows like mentioned below:

image = [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWx4u.png)

I just want details of separate rows in python console like :-

```
row1 = ['name':row1,'meetid':121121,'neetpass: 12121','endtime':8:15]
```

somehow like that

Comment: so you need to go from excel to dictionary right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using `read_excel` to read the excel file
`.loc` will read your data as per row
The header `name` , `meet_id` , `meet_pass` , `meet_link` , `start_time` , `end_time` will not be counted
so your first index `[0]` is actually `row1`

```
from pandas import read_excel
data = read_excel("the_data.xlsx")
row1 = data.loc[0]
dictionary = row1.to_dict()
print(dictionary)
```

Here is the output

```
{'name': 'row1', 'meed_id': 'idgotit', 'meet_pass': 'pass', 'meet_link': 'link', 'start_time': datetime.time(21, 43), 'end_time': datetime.time(10, 15)}
```

Comment: Thanks You So Muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This was what i needed

Comment: You explained me very well

Comment: @harish795 good for you than , goodluck on your `meet` proejct

Comment: Hey Now Tell How Can I Accces that: like i need the info from name cell of row1 how can i do that?

Comment: @harish795 im giving you example , `dictionary['name']` will outputting `row1` because in the dict , `"name" : "row1"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx')
print(df.to_dict('index'))
```

All the rows are in the dictionary now.

Output:

```
{0: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 1: {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}}
```

Each row can then be accessed with row number as key.